# Lambda Query GroupBy with boolean values

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, lambda, boolean, linq-group

I have a number of instances where I need to return a data list that uses `.GroupBy`. In addition to dates and integers I also need to return Boolean values, which I cannot seem to do. An example model:

```
public class HolidayCheckList
{
    public DateTime startDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime endDate { get; set; }
    public int stafferId { get; set; }
    public bool startTime { get; set; }
    public bool endTime { get; set; }
}
```

Below is the controller as it is at present:

```
var model = _db.AnnualLeaves
    .Where(r => r.StartDate <= tTE && r.EndDate >= tTS)
    .GroupBy(r => r.tBooked) 
    .Select(m => new HolidayCheckList
    {
        startDate = m.Max(r => r.StartDate),
        endDate = m.Max(r => r.EndDate),
        stafferId = m.Min(r => r.StafferId)
    });

    return View(model.ToList());
```

This does what I need. However, in addition to the `startDate` and `endDate` I need to return the `startTime` and `endTime`, which are Boolean values, to the View. I don't know whether I need an aggregate operator I am not aware of, need to include in the `.GroupBy` statement or maybe need a nested query. No doubt it will be something far simpler.

I did consider changing the data type to an integer, but would like to know if there is a way of doing this "properly".

As an aside, is there a learning resource or documentation for lambda queries? I can find basic information but nothing that details how `.GroupBy` works, or what the aggregate operators are.

Comment: The answer (to whether you want to use an aggregate or include the properties in your `GroupBy` lambda) depends on if different values in those properties mean different groups. In other words, if two `HolidayChecklist`s are the same except for `startTime` and `endTime`, should they be grouped together?

Comment: Where the data is written to the table I can ensure that the startTime and endTime values are the same for any group, although I would prefer to use an aggregate such as Min / Max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're certain that all of the `startTime` and `endTime` values will be the same (or you don't care), you could use `.First` to select the first item in the group's `startTime` and `endTime` values:

```
var model = _db.AnnualLeaves
    .Where(r => r.StartDate <= tTE && r.EndDate >= tTS)
    .GroupBy(r => r.tBooked) 
    .Select(m => new HolidayCheckList
    {
        startDate = m.Max(r => r.StartDate),
        endDate = m.Max(r => r.EndDate),
        stafferId = m.Min(r => r.StafferId),
        startTime = m.Select(r => r.StartTime).First(),
        endTime = m.Select(r => r.EndTime).First()
    });
```

A good resource for lambdas is the [Lambda Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx) article on MSDN.

The [Aggregation Operations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546138.aspx) looks like a good overview of the various aggregate operations available in LINQ. Unfortunately the examples are in VB.NET though.

Comment: That looks like the ticket... I will test it as soon as I get home - I tried using .First and .Last but was putting it in the wrong place, ie where the .Select is in the code above. For me, it should work with startTime .First and endTime .Last.
I was so close! Thanks.

Comment: Using the above I got the following, nut swapping to FirstOrDefault fixed it... +$exception {"The method 'First' can only be used as a final query operation. Consider using the method 'FirstOrDefault' in this instance instead."} System.Exception {System.NotSupportedException}
Thanks, you got me over the line! Oh, and for the links too.